# Get R G B colors from DataBuffer byte array

Tags: java, bufferedimage

these few lines retrieve an array of all pixels of an image.

```
ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(f);
Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(is);
ImageReader imageReader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
imageReader.setInput(is);
BufferedImage image = imageReader.read(0);
final byte[] a = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

How can I retrieve actual R G B channels for a pixel (for example 0,0)?

**EDIT**
I'm using this array because of faster access to the image. That's why I'm not using higher APIs' methods like *getRGB* or *getSample*...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `image.getType() == TYPE_INT_RGB` then you have an array like this:

```
R, G, B, R, G, B, R, G, B, ...
```

You can access the values of pixel (x,y) via

```
int width = image.getWidth();

...

byte R = a[3*(x+y*width)];
byte G = a[1+3*(x+y*width)];
byte B = a[2+3*(x+y*width)];
```

There are several other imagetypes to consider as you can read in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#field_detail).

The access method basically stays the same, you just have different color ordering or an additional alpha channel. However, for those 4 channel pixels you have to adjust the formular for first channel of the pixel (x,y) to

```
byte A = a[4*(x+y*width)];
```

Comment: How can I call getPixel() method on a simple byte array ?!?